# how to print out autoincrement ID in Activerecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `before_save` in my model

before saving the record to the database...I'd like to print out the autoincremented `ID` that will be inserted.  My table has a column `id` in it.

I tried

```
before_save :printId

def printId
   puts "ID that will be inserted is: " + self.id
end
```

this does not work...

Comment: Where would you like such a printed statement to show up? in the console? in a view?

Comment: The question is: What do you need it for? If you need it beforehand for some reason, probably something is wrong with your application design or your understandings of ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 3):

Try `after_save`.

Comment: As mentioned by Beerlington, the id is nil until save occurs.

Answer (score 1):

The autoincrement ID does not exist for an ActiveRecord object until it has been saved. It's possible to get the next autoincrement ID for a table, but this doesn't guarantee that the ID will be given to your object when saved since another record may have been added in the meantime.